# What could this line of Javascript code possibly do?

Tags: javascript

I just stumbled upon a line of code in a project I'm currently working in. I feel I'm decent at Javascript but to be honest, I have no clue as of what the following line of code actually does:

```
var date = new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, [null,].concat(buildDateParams(spec, base))));
```

Can someone of you Javascript gurus possibly shed some light on this?

`buildDateParams` seems to build an array of values. For completeness' sake, here's the function:

```
function buildDateParams(spec, base) {
    if (!spec.match(specRegExp)) {
        throw new Error('Invalid spec string');
    }
    var specParts = spec.toLowerCase().split(':');
    let params = [];
    for (let fieldIndex in fields) {
        let field = fields[fieldIndex];
        let specPart = (fieldIndex < specParts.length)
            ? specParts[fieldIndex]
            : '0';
        if (!specPart.length) {
            specPart = 'b';
        }
        let param = 0;
        if (specPart.substr(0, 1) === 'b') {
            param = base[field.getter]();
            specPart = specPart.substr(1);
        }
        if (specPart.length) {
            param += parseInt(specPart);
        }
        params.push(param);
    }
    return params;
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like that function returns an array of numbers, not strings.

Comment: I haven't investigated further into that function, you could easily be right. Will adjust it to "values" instead of "strings".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's sort-of a complicated version of

```
Date.bind(null, buildDateParams(spec, base));
```

except one that works; the idea is that it wants to bind the Date constructor to a set of parameters that are generated by that `buildDateParams()` function.

With the ES2015 spread syntax, it'd work to write

```
Date.bind(null, ... buildDateParams(spec, base));
```

It's just creating a function that returns a Date instance according to some pre-arranged parameters.

Also, because of that stray comma in the `[null,]` array initializer, it might have issues in IE (though a modern IE with `.bind()` might not interpret that array as having two elements).

Comment: "except one that works" - does that actually mean that your more concise version does not work? In contrast to the code I found in the project you are suggesting calling bind with two parameters `null` and the array returned by that function, whereas in my code sample it's only one argument, and array containing `null` as its first element.

Comment: @connexo yes sorry my initial response missed the subtlety of the return value from that function being an array to be used as parameters; the `...` syntax would handle that. I give credit to half a cup of coffee for helping me realize that :)

Comment: @connexo also note that the version you posted could have used `Date.bind.apply` instead of `Function.prototype.bind.apply`